# filter ICollectionView dynamically with multiple list of filters

Tags: c#, wpf, linq

I have a ICollectionView from datagrid.
It has 4 fields Name,SchoolName,Gender,Class.
Interface has one search box where user can enter comma separated values and ICollectionView will be filtered.

It is working with single value, how can i do this to work with comma separated list.

```cs
List<string> NameList = filterText.Split(',').ToList();
List<string> SchoolNameList = filterText.Split(',').ToList();
List<string> GenderList = filterText.Split(',').ToList();
List<string> ClassList = filterText.Split(',').ToList();
```

Below is the code working with single filter

```cs
var query1 = new Predicate<object>(x => ((View)x).Name.ToLower().Contains(filterText));
var query2 = new Predicate<object>(x => ((View)x).SchoolName.ToLower().Contains(filterText));
var query3 = new Predicate<object>(x => ((View)x).Gender.ToLower().Contains(filterText));
var query4 = new Predicate<object>(x => ((View)x).Class.ToLower().Contains(filterText));

yourCostumFilter = new Predicate<object>(x =>
                                (query1(x) || query2(x) || query3(x) || query4(x) ));


view.Filter = yourCostumFilter;
```

How can it will work with NameList, SchoolNameList, GenderList and ClassList. Please help.

Answer (score 0):

The trick is to use Any() on the list you get after splitting the search filter and check if the current value is in the collection.
As `filterText.Split(',')` will return in all 4 cases the same collection there is no need to do the split four times. Also you may use Any on any kind of collection so there is no need for use `ToList()`.

That will be working like this:

```
public ICollectionView FilteredCollection
{
    get
    {
        if (this.MyFullList == null) return null;
        var source = CollectionViewSource.GetDefaultView(this.MyFullList);
        source.Filter = p => DoFilter((MyObject)p);
        return source;
    }
}

private bool DoFilter(MyObject t)
{
    try
    {
        var filterList = filterText.Split(',');
        return (filterList.Any(f => f.Equals(t.Name, StringComparison.OrdinalIgnoreCase)) ||
               filterList.Any(f => f.Equals(t.SchoolName, StringComparison.OrdinalIgnoreCase)) ||
               filterList.Any(f => f.Equals(t.Gender, StringComparison.OrdinalIgnoreCase)) ||
               filterList.Any(f => f.Equals(t.Class, StringComparison.OrdinalIgnoreCase)));
    }
    catch
    {
        return true;
    }
}
```